# slick js target each slide by number

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I cant figure out what's wrong with the slide events here. I need to target each slide in a slider but the onafterchange does not seem to work

```
$('.home .slick').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    onAfterChange:function(slickSlider){

        if(slickSlider.currentSlide === 0){

              $('.scene-2').parallax('disable');

              $('.scene-1').parallax('enable');

        } 
        if (slickSlider.currentSlide === 1) {

              $('.scene-1').parallax('disable');

              $('.scene-2').parallax('enable');

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since slick version 1.4 you should target slick events as follows:

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
   // your code here
});
```